# How to include a third-party jar-file in compilation and runtime using command prompt in Windows 10?

Tags: java, compilation, classpath

I'm trying to understand the inclusion of third party jar files in a java project using only the command line in Windows 10.

Specifically, I try to include the file json-20200518.jar in my "project" so that I can use the java object JSONObject in the project.

My java file:

```
package com.mypackage.example;

import org.json.JSONObject;

class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ... program logic
    }
}
```

location of my java file (Examp.java):

> ./com/mypackage/example

location of jar file:

> ./jars

using cmd win10 I compile:

> javac -cp "C:\Users\pfort\Desktop\java\jars\json-20200518.jar" "C:\Users\pfort\Desktop\java\com\mypackage\example\Examp.java"

compilation is successful.

Run:

> java -cp "C:\Users\pfort\Desktop\java\jars\json-20200518.jar" com.mypackage.example.Examp

I get a report:

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.mypackage.example.Pokus
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mypackage.example.Pokus

Second attempt:

> java -cp "C:\Users\pfort\Desktop\java\jars\json-20200518.jar" "C:\Users\pfort\Desktop\java\com\mypackage\example\Pokus"

But the same error message comes back to me.
Where am I going wrong?
 Is it the wrong structure?
 I don't get it, the compilation is successful but the run does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiled `Examp.class` file isn't part of `json-20200518.jar`, so you'll need to add the directory containing it to the command line. Assuming it's the current directory (`.`):

```
java -cp "C:\Users\pfort\Desktop\java\jars\json-20200518.jar;." com.mypackage.example.Examp
```